# Dynamic name of array in document using doc().set- Firebase function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am not able to assign **dynamic name** to my array (I want to assign value of **auth_ID** as name of array).

Problem - it is saving **auth_ID** as text in db, whereas i want its value.

Here is my code:

```
    exports.insert_totalcalllogs = functions.firestore
.document('calllogs/{calllogsId}')
.onCreate(
    async (snapshot: { data: () => { (): any; new(): any; entryDate_show:any; authid: any; fullname:any; }; },context:any) => {
      // todos details.
      const text = snapshot.data();
      const entryDate_show = text.entryDate_show;

      const auth_ID = text.authid; // want this to be name of array

      const fullname = text.fullname;
  admin.firestore().collection("totalcalllogs").doc(entryDate_show).set({
    auth_ID: [
         { number: 1, fullname: fullname , authid: auth_ID},
       ],
    age: 12,
  })
  .then(function() {
     console.log("Document successfully written!");
  })
  .catch(function(error: any) {
     console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
  });
...// some code
```

See image of console:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a variable as the name of property in a JavaScript object, use the square bracket notation when building the object:

```
  admin.firestore().collection("totalcalllogs").doc(entryDate_show).set({
    [auth_ID]: [
         { number: 1, fullname: fullname , authid: auth_ID},
       ],
    age: 12,
  })
```

Note the square brackets around `[auth_ID]`.

Comment: Little bit of an extra explanation: If you don't use the square brackets (`[ ... ]`), then `auth_ID` is simply treated as a string literal (`"auth_ID": [ ... ]`) and not as the variable `auth_ID`.